# Does the IVP $y'=1+y^{2/3}$ with $y(0)=0$ have a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the IVP $y'=1+y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ with $y(0)=0$, I've to show it has unique solution

I can't apply Picard's theroem here since $f(x,y)=1+y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not Lipschitz , but I can apply Peano's Theorem on some rectangle having $(0,0)$ as an interior point that will give me a solution to this IVP. But how do I show it is unique? Even if I directly integrate it I'll get one solution but still uniqueness is not there!